# Is there a free Bootstrap CMS with e-commerce module?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, content-management-system, e-commerce

I am searching on the web to find a free to use CMS which has the standard feautures and the most important part an e-commerce module.
I have found a few free Bootstrap CMS like; BatFlat, BuildEngine, Bolt, Doorget and a lot more, but none of them has a e-commerce module.

It won't be a big deal to spend a little bit of money.

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: A CMS is very different then a working e-commerce solution. Consider using a service like Shopify.com for e-commerce because you will be up and running very quickly. Otherwise if you have a few months to do this - choose a programming language, then choose an open source e-commerce solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Magento](https://magento.com/) and search for some twitter bootstrap theme. There should be plenty, although some of them do not cover all its features, since it is quite big.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can get it here it included a full shop and much more: https://www.jakweb.ch/download/f/6/cms

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please use a comment for this type of suggestions.

Comment: @ankitsuthar, new users under 50 reputations cannot [comment everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).